# Android Studio 1.1.0 Gradle project sync failed Error importing a Gradle project on a OSX

Tags: android, macos, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, cradle

I just installed gradle in this folder:
/Users/joanet/Development/gradle-2.3

edit the file launchd.conf

```
sudo vim /etc/launchd.conf
```

to set the variable GRAILS_HOME

```
setenv GRAILS_HOME /Users/joanet/Development/gradle-2.3
```

then I've imported the project https://github.com/NordicSemiconductor/Android-nRF-Toolbox

using File -> Import project

but I got this error:
**Gradle project sync failed** and **Error: Configuration with name 'default' not found in Android Studio**

I have tried this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8RwVvZtNTaM
but it has not worked

[image]

Here the file build.gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

and here /app/build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion '22.0.0'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "no.nordicsemi.android.nrftoolbox"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 30
        versionName "1.12.1"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    compile project(':..:DFULibrary:dfu')
    compile files('libs/achartengine-1.1.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/nrf-logger-v2.0.jar')
}
```

here settings.gradle:

```
include ':app', '..:DFULibrary:dfu'
```

and here gradle-wrapper.properties:

```
#Wed Apr 10 15:27:10 PDT 2013
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip


// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Comment: Post **BOTH** of your `build.gradle` files. You are missing your "app" `build.gradle`.

Comment: Post your `settings.gradle` file as well, please.

Comment: I took the time to download the project so I could help walk you through it. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just downloaded the project.

### First look at the `settings.gradle`:

```
include ':app', '..:DFULibrary:dfu'
```

There is a project, `..:DFULibrary:dfu`, that is not provided in the Github project.

### Second, look at the `app/build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    compile project(':..:DFULibrary:dfu') // <-- You do not have this
    compile files('libs/achartengine-1.1.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/nrf-logger-v2.0.jar')
}
```

The line, `compile project(':..:DFULibrary:dfu')` is trying to compile a project that you do not have.

### Third, read the `README.md`:

> **Dependencies**
>
> In order to compile the project the DFU Library is required. This
>   project may be found here:
>   https://github.com/NordicSemiconductor/Android-DFU-Library. Please
>   clone the nRF Toolbox and the DFU Library to the same root folder. The
>   dependency is already configured in the gradle and set to
>   ..:DFULibrary:dfu module.
>
> The nRF Toolbox also uses the nRF Logger API library which may be
>   found here: https://github.com/NordicSemiconductor/nRF-Logger-API. The
>   library (jar file) and is located in the libs folder and a jar with
>   its source code in the source folder in the app module. This library
>   allows the app to create log entries in the nRF Logger application.
>   Please, read the library documentation on GitHub for more information
>   about the usage and permissions.
>
> The graph in HRM profile is created using the AChartEngine v1.1.0
>   contributed based on the Apache 2.0 license.

The `owner` of the project provides you with the other project site's URL here: https://github.com/NordicSemiconductor/Android-DFU-Library.

### Conclusion:

Simply do `git clone https://github.com/NordicSemiconductor/Android-DFU-Library.git` just like he says in his instructions in the **same** folder as your current project. Everything should work after that.

#### How to:

1. `git clone https://github.com/NordicSemiconductor/Android-nRF-Toolbox.git`
2. `git clone https://github.com/NordicSemiconductor/Android-DFU-Library.git`
3. Rename `Android-DFU-Library` to `DFULibrary`. (mv Android-DFU-Library DFULibrary)

You should be all set!